# SSIS SQL output as XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 \ SQL Server 2014 and have a SSIS package.  Part if this involves exporting a file in XML.  For my source I have an OLE connection with the following SQL Command:

```
DECLARE @XMLOutput XML
DECLARE @XMLOutputChar nvarchar(max)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('Testing' as ns)

SELECT @XMLOutput =
(
SELECT ISNULL(RTRIM(T1.[field1]),'')AS field1
FROM   MyTable T1 


    FOR XML PATH('Test'),TYPE, ROOT('TestData'),ELEMENTS XSINIL
)

SET @XMLOutputChar = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@XMLOutput)

SELECT @XMLOutputChar AS XMLOutput
```

The issue is, if there is no records in [field1], then the 2nd XML tag does not get created in the XML file and all I get is:

```
<field1>
```

If there is data in field1, then it works fine e.g.:

```
<field1>blah blah blah</field1>
```

I'm checking for NULL and also right trimming - what am I missing?

Comment: If there are *no* values, what you should actually get back is `NULL`. If there are values but they're empty, you should see `<field1/>`, not `<field1>`. I cannot conceive of any way to get an output that includes an unclosed tag; at least not on the SQL Server side -- possibly on the SSIS side depending on how the query gets executed. Have you tried executing this query in Management Studio to see what the full output is?

Comment: Wait, I'm wrong, I can conceive of a way, which is if the XML actually includes characters outside ASCII. Slapping a directive on the XML where you say the encoding is UTF-8 does not actually make it so -- the encoding is necessarily UTF-16 as that's what SQL Server uses for its Unicode strings. Changing that certainly won't hurt, even if it doesn't necessarily fix it.